# If Else Statement Toggle For A 'Help' Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a help button that displays a help message, and if you hit it again, the help message goes away (I change the opacity to 0). I want to have it toggle on and off. I tried an if statement and the button stopped working completely. Here is my javascript:

```
function messageToggle() {
    if (document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "1.0") {
        document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "0";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "1.0";
    }
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<button onclick="messageToggle()">Help</button>
<p id="helpMessage">Help Message Goes Here</p>
```

Any suggestions as to how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use == instead of = and 1 instead of 1.0
Corrected:

```js
document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "1.0";

function messageToggle(){
var op = document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity;
console.log(op);
if(document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity == "1"){
     document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "0"; 
  console.log("0");

}else{
      document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity = "1"; 
   console.log("Else");
}

}
```

```html
<button onclick="messageToggle()">Help</button>
<p id="helpMessage">Help Message Goes Here</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use comparison operator (`==` or `===`) when writing conditions:

```
if (document.getElementById("helpMessage").style.opacity == 1) {
  ...
}
```

The code in your program is syntactically correct, but executing assignment (instead of comparison) will always result in "true" branch. Hence the complete disappearance of the help message.

Comment: I tried that, but the button still doesn't work. I inserted an alert to make sure the function was being executed and it was. It seems like the if statement is being avoided all together.

Comment: You need to use `'1'` or better `1` in place of `'1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to toggle it on and off see the below code

```js
function messageToggle() {
  $("#helpMessage").toggle("slow", function() {
    
    //animation done

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="messageToggle()">Help</button>
<p id="helpMessage">Help Message Goes Here</p>
```